# Why does GetLastError have an error before my program begins?

Tags: delphi, winapi, error-handling, delphi-xe8

While using `GetLastError` after calling a Windows API function wrapper like `ExtractShortPathName` I noticed that `GetLastError` returns a non-zero error code regardless of whether the call to `ExtractShortPathName` succeeded or failed. In fact, there seems to be a "last error" before my program even executes, e.g.

```
program TestGetLastError;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

var
  ErrorCode: Integer;

begin
  try
    ErrorCode := GetLastError;
    if ErrorCode <> 0 then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      WriteLn(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

results in:

```
EOSError: System Error.  Code: 122.
The data area passed to a system call is too small
```

Am I misunderstanding something or doing something wrong?

If the Delphi run-time is doing something that results in `GetLastError` being set, what is the correct way to clear that error before my program starts executing? Should I use `SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS);` like this example from the Delphi API documentation:

```
procedure TForm2.btRaiseLastClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { Set the last OS error to a bogus value. }
  System.SetLastError(ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED);

  try
    RaiseLastOSError();
  except
    on Ex : EOSError do
      MessageDlg('Caught an OS error with code: ' + IntToStr(Ex.ErrorCode), mtError, [mbOK], 0);
  end;

  { Let the Delphi Exception dialog appear. }
  RaiseLastOSError(ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY);

  { Finally set the last error to none. }
  System.SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS);

  if GetLastError() <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
    MessageDlg('Whoops, something went wrong in the mean time!', mtError, [mbOK], 0);

  { No exception should be thrown here because last OS error is "ERROR_SUCCESS". }
  CheckOSError(GetLastError());
end;
```

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/LastOSError_(Delphi)

Comment: Don't call GetLastError unless something fails. It's meaningless.

Comment: I have the exact same result. Interestingly, when I remove the `SysUtils` from uses clause (and all that requires it), I get error code `50` instead (`The request is not supported.`). But @Jonathan's right, there's no reason to call `GetLastError` unless an error has actually occurred. Imagine an error which occurred 10 minutes ago in an entirely different window. Then, for whatever reason, you call `GetLastError`, thus returning the same code from 10 minutes ago.

Comment: The API documentation indicates that GetLastError is only of use if a) an API call fails, and b) the function that fails indicates that you can use GetLastError for more information about why. Randomly calling it or calling it without a failure in a function documented to set it on failure is meaningless. You can't call GetLastError unless you know an error occurred, and only if you're calling it after a specific function you called indicates it failed.

Comment: So the answer to *Am I misunderstanding something or doing something wrong?* is *both*. :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks - I was assuming that a successful API call would set the last error to 0, which is obviously incorrect. The particular API call that set me on this path (no pun intended) was ExtractShortPathName, which doesn't indicate whether it succeeded or failed, other than if you assume that it failed if it returns an empty string. Am I right to think that it's up to me to figure out whether an error occurred and only then use GetLastError to find out more about it?

Comment: @KendallLister `ExtractShortPathName` is not a Windows API call, it's built-in to the Delphi SysUtils, which in turn calls `GetShortPathName`, which is an API call :)

Comment: Sure, but it wraps a call to `GetShortPathName`.

Comment: According to the docs of `GetShortPathName`, if it fails, you should call `GetLastError`. "Fails" as in it returns zero, which is one thing `ExtractShortPathName` does not do.

Comment: Yes, I saw that - the trick is that the Delphi wrapper functions don't always surface the API call's result. In this case from the implementation of ExtractShortPathName it seems that a result of 0 will mean an empty string is returned.

Comment: Well, I have definitely learned something - thanks for your help everyone. Would one of you fine people like to write up an answer for me to accept? If not, I can summarise one.

Comment: Well, if it bothers you, you can "dismiss" error status every time you handle the error condition by `SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx)'s documentation indicates that is only of use if

- an API call fails, and
- the function that fails indicates that you can use GetLastError for more information about why. 
  From that documentation (**emphasis mine**)

> The return value is the calling thread's last-error code.
>
> **The Return Value section of the documentation for each function that sets the last-error code notes the conditions under which the function sets the last-error code.** Most functions that set the thread's last-error code set it when they fail. However, some functions also set the last-error code when they succeed. **If the function is not documented to set the last-error code, the value returned by this function is simply the most recent last-error code to have been set; some functions set the last-error code to 0 on success and others do not.**

This indicates that calling it without first having a failure in a function documented to set it on failure is meaningless. You can't call GetLastError unless you know an error occurred, and only if you're calling it after a specific function you called indicates it failed.

Answer (score 13):

The value returned by `GetLastError()` is only relevant immediately after a Windows API call that has failed and where the documentation for that function specifies that extended error information is available by calling `GetLastError()`.

Calling it outside of that context will return something from an earlier call, which could be from your code, the Delphi runtime, a DLL that you have called or even something in the Windows API...

As the Windows API documentation for `GetLastError()` states:

> You should call the GetLastError function immediately when a
>   function's return value indicates that such a call will return useful
>   data.